# Report Services failed to show Datepicker in Internet Information Services ,but succesfully in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I Have A problem with my Project ,about report ,

I want to create monthly report about employee attandance , i have publish my application into my Internet Information Services (ISS) ,but when i want to take data based on a range date ,the datepicker was not shown ,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDot8.png)

i try to check my application, and run it using my visual studion ,and it can show datepicker like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfzvS.png)

Do i need to custom setting in my ISS ?
How can i Solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't deployed your date picker control (perhaps some JavaScript thing) when you deployed your application to IIS. Press F12 to open the developer console, switch to network tab and look for error 404s; it indicates things your code is trying to load, that is missing from the server. If not in the Network tab, check the console tab to see if any JavaScript errors are preventing your control from loading

Comment: i have found several errors ,after press F12 ,but same thing happen in my localhost too,what should i do ?

Comment: I can't really give any more advice than I already have, because there just isn't enough info in your question. You seem to be claiming that everything is identical between the two systems but this is clearly not the case. You'll have to keep working at the problem using the inspection tools available to you to find why the control shows in debug but not production. Use the DOM inspector to see differences in the documents, look for code that hides DOM elements if something fails, cehck that your server file system is the same as the local filesystem etc

Comment: what version of SSRS are you using?